# Change initial element of a list keeping the sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have an algorithm that outputs a list in a specific order, for example:

[0 4 3 2 1 5]

I want to reorder the list to start with the element '1' and keep the sequence, so my output would be:

[1 5 0 4 3 2]

I've searched and tried different possibilities but I'm still struggling with it.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Rotate: `lst[:] = lst[4:] + lst[:4]`

Comment: @schwobaseggl use `index()` instead of 4

Comment: Then it is no longer a simple comment-worty one-liner if I don't call it twice (named assignments notwithstanding) =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst = [0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
```

to rotate it into position:

```
i = lst.index(1)
lst = lst[i:] + lst[:i]
```

Comment: Can make one-liner with Walrus operator: `lst = lst[(p:=lst.index(1)):] + lst[:p]`

Comment: I am well aware, as seen in my comments. However, it only works in the most recent Python versions and does not make it more readable or performant.